# Selenium failing to identify an actionLink on the AAD login page

Tags: selenium, ui-automation

I am new to Selenium. Could someone help with the below error scenario while trying to click on the `actionLink` on the Azure AD login page.

`<a class="actionLink" href="#">
<br>
<br>
<p> class="normalText" style="background-color: transparent;">Sign in with a username and password instead </p>`

with these options:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("p.normalText")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Name("actionLink")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Sign in with a username and password instead")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Name("Sign in with a username and password instead")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sign in with a username and password instead")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Sign in with a username and password instead")).Click();
```

All of them failed with the below exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Sign in with a username and password instead"}

Is it somehow disabled to avoid bot traffic? Could someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1):

You should try following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath('//p[contains(text(),"Sign in with a username and password instead")]')).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("actionLink")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use :  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in with a username and password instead ")).click();

Secondly, I am quite confuse its case sensetive or not, so try to use "F" in small letter.